# Specify XML schema data type of decimal or blank

Tags: xml, xsd

Is there a way in an XML schema to specify that an element may contain either an empty string or a decimal?

If I specify the type as `xs:decimal` like this:

```
<xs:element name="Sample" type="xs:decimal" />
```

then a blank value would not pass validation:

```
<Sample/>
```

(I realize that the best way to indicate no value would be to not include the element, but I was wondering if there was a way to allow blank or decimal.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `nillable="true"`.